# Como alterar o nome de uma coluna

Tags: r

Tenho um data.frame, alterei a classe dos dados da coluna data e posteriormente separei a coluna outras três através do comando Separate, cujos nomes ficaram como %Y, %m e %d, gostaria de alterar esses nomes para ano, mês e dia. Porém, ao tentar renomear as colunas, através do comando Rename dá erro.

```
> as.data <- as.Date(dados$data)

> meus.dados <- separate(data = dados, col = data, into = c("%Y", "%m","%d"), sep = "-")

> meus.dados[1:5, 1:9]
```

Source: local data frame [5 x 9]

```
   posicao    %Y    %m    %d              especie    BF   CA2    CB    CP
     (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)                (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1  direita  2012    05    22     Canis familiaris     0     0     0     0
2  direita  2012    05    22     Canis familiaris     0     0     0     0
3 esquerda  2012    05    24 Dasypus novemcinctus     0     0     0     1
4 esquerda  2012    05    25     Canis familiaris     1     0     0     0
5 esquerda  2012    05    26 Dasypus novemcinctus     0     0     0     1

> rename(meus.dados, ano=" %Y", mes="%m", dia="%d")
 Error: Arguments to rename must be unquoted variable names. Arguments ano, mes, dia are not.
```

Não sei o que fazer!!

Comment: Por que não já criar com os nomes definitivos na função `separate`? `meus.dados <- separate(data = dados, col = data, into = c("ano", "mes","dia"), sep = "-")`

Comment: Obrigada!!! Deu certo!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar a função `names` para obter, e *também para alterar* o nome das colunas. No seu caso, você pode usar `names(meus.dados)[2:4] <- c("ano", "mes", "dia")`. O exemplo completo abaixo mostra ele sendo usado:

```
meus.dados <- data.frame(
    posicao = c("direita", "direita", "esquerda", "esquerda"),
    YY = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012"),
    MM = rep("05", 4),
    DD = c("22", "22", "24", "25"),
    especie = c("cf", "cf", "dn", "cf")
)

names(meus.dados)[2:4] <- c("ano", "mes", "dia")

meus.dados
```

Answer (score 4):

Como os nomes das variáveis possuem carcteres não reconhecidos diretamente pelo R, você precisa usar o caractere: **`** envolta do nome delas. Então seria necessário fazer assim:

```
meus.dados <- data_frame(
  posicao = c("direita", "direita", "esquerda", "esquerda"),
  "%Y" = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012"),
  "%m" = rep("05", 4),
  "%d" = c("22", "22", "24", "25"),
  especie = c("cf", "cf", "dn", "cf")
)

rename(meus.dados, ano = `%Y`, mes = `%m`, dia = `%d`)
```

Mas, como o @molx disse no comentário vc já poderia colocar esses nomes diretamente pela função `separate`.

Comment: Para grandes bancos é aconselhável usar a função rename.vars(data, c("x","y"), c("new_x","new_y")).

Answer (score 0):

Podemos usar a função `rename_with` do `dplyr`, a qual faz uso de funções (como aquelas do pacote `stringr`) para procurar padrões e realizar a substituição do nome.

Dados:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  posicao = c("direita", "direita", "esquerda", "esquerda"),
  "%Y" = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012"),
  "%m" = rep("05", 4),
  "%d" = c("22", "22", "24", "25"),
  especie = c("cf", "cf", "dn", "cf")
)
```

Função:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  rename_with(.data = ., .cols = 2:4, 
          .fn = str_replace, pattern = ".*", 
          replacement = str_c(c("ano", "mes", "dia")))


#   posicao  ano mes dia especie
#1  direita 2012  05  22      cf
#2  direita 2012  05  22      cf
#3 esquerda 2012  05  24      dn
#4 esquerda 2012  05  25      cf
```